# can I use parallel controller in jmter script already transaction controller is there

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

can I use parallel controller in jmeter script already transaction controller is there or else I uncheck the run thread consecutively at a time, because I have 1o thread group each have multiple transaction controller.

Answer (score 0):

As per [documentation](https://github.com/Blazemeter/jmeter-bzm-plugins/blob/master/parallel/Parallel.md):

> **Limitations**
>
> Parallel Controller does not support work with Transaction Controller so if used you can get an unexpected results. If you decide to use these controllers together familiarize yourself with already known problems that described in [roadmap](https://github.com/Blazemeter/jmeter-bzm-plugins/blob/master/parallel/Parallel.md#roadmap)

So the answer is "yes, you can as long as you're okay with the limitations"

The question is "what you're trying to achieve"?

Given Parallel Controller executes its children in parallel if you tick "Generate parent sample" it will report the longest child duration which makes sense.

[Transaction Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-transaction-controller) returns a synthetic Sample Result holding cumulative execution time of its children, it doesn't care whether it is a normal Sampler or a Parallel Controller.